# Download csv file from https tableau server with python using request and basic authentication

Tags: python, python-requests, basic-authentication, tableau-api

I have a tableau 10.0 server. I have a view at `https://example.com/views/SomeReport/Totals`. In a browser, if I navigate to `https://example.com/views/SomeReport/Totals.csv` I am prompted to login and then the view is downloaded as a csv file.

Im trying to download this same file using python

Details

- tableau 10.0
- python 2.7
- tableau running on windows
- python running on a mac OSX El capitan

Here is what I tried:

```
        tableau_file_path = '{tableau_path}{tableau_view}{file_ext}'.format(**cur_file)
        local_path = cur_file['local_path']
        user = 'xxxx'
        password = 'xxxx'

        # print tableau_file_path  # outputs https://example.com/views/SomeReport/Totals.csv
        # print local_path         # outputs ../generated_resources/Some Folder Name/Totals.csv 

        r = requests.get(tableau_file_path, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password), stream=True, timeout=5)
        # also tried auth=(user, password)
        print r.status_code   # outputs 401
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(local_path, 'wb') as f: 
                f.write(r.content)
```

I feel like this *should* work, but it does not. I get `401` for the status

If I remove the `.csv` from the path, it works and I do get the actual tableau dashboard page. But I need the csv file not the html from the tableau dashboard

I've copied the username and password directly from my code and pasted them into the form that pops up in my browser and the creds work seemingly ruling out issues with wrong creds.

#### This works for normal webpages, but does not work when hitting the url prompts a file download. How can I make this work with file downloads?

**Note** I am open to other methods of downloading the file with python

Comment: status code 401 means unauthorized (also when authentication fails)...are you sure the username and password are correct?

Comment: @jatinderjit positive, I copied them directly from the code and pasted them into the web form, right in,  no issue

Comment: you can use DevTools in Chrome or Firefox to see what browser sends to server. Maybe it sends extre data, cookies, encrypted password, etc.

Comment: @furas I cant see it in the dev tools because its a file being downloaded not  an actual page but that made me think. If I remove the `.csv` from the path, it works and I do get the actual page. But I need the file not the html from the tableau dashboard

Comment: @DelightedD0D  many servers require authentication Token instead of HTTP Basic Auth

Unless we get a accessible link OR HTML messages from your browser it would be difficult to provide a solution

Comment: @DelightedD0D I don't talk about `response` - HTML page, downloaded file, but about `request` which browser sends when you click link, or press button in login window. You have to see what information browser sends in `request` and then you have to use the same data in your `requests.get()`. And you can use DevTools to see browser `request`.

Comment: @furas I get that, but when I enter the url in the browser or click the link, the file is downloaded, no navigation occurs. Where can I see the header data for that? It doesnt show up in the network tab like ajax requests do

Comment: it doesn't show login window because probably browser or server remember your login/password and you have to clear cookies or restart browser to logout.

Comment: @furas I found a "HTTP live headers" chrome extension that lets me see them, digging into them now ty

Comment: @DelightedD0D `HTTP live headers` is nice tool but it doesn't show you information if you don't logout first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say that Tableau is not doing HTTP basic authentication, but rather have their own method. So when you try to access the thing through requests, it rejects it because it doesn't know how to auth like that.

When you access it as a human, it knows to redirect you to their login page and do the whole "login flow" and finally redirect you to the proper download page. However, requests tries to clearly identify itself as a robot, and uses a special UserAgent string (just "requests" I believe), which is why the server decides to return a straight up 401.

Depending on your use case, you could log in manually, and see what cookies are being set by Tableau, and include those in your request.
You might also change your user agent to a browser one (they start with "Mozilla 5.0/" in the vast-vast majority of cases), and see if you download the login page. If that's the case, you could reverse-engineer some of their login process - enough to find out how they submit the user and password, and how they redirect to the page you want. After that, you'll most likely make a POST to their login infrastructure with that data and the required redirect.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, would this hold true even though when I use the dashboard page url, the basic authentication works as expected?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I think in this case there's something else happening, than what I described. You might want to check all the info the server returns. Perhaps there's more info in the response body? I would try to simulate as close as possible the request that Chrome makes to Tableau and which works - this means headers, query parameters etc. and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

Tableau exposes a REST API which you can use to download the csv file. API end point is `https://MY-SERVER/api/VERSION_NUM/auth/signin` where `VERSION_NUM` depends on the version of tableau server and mapping for API version & Tableau server version can be found [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_versions.htm). For authentication to work successfully, you'll need to get a token using above mentioned API end point. You can then pass this token in header parameter `'X-tableau-auth'`. Here's the code:

```
import requests, json
from config import USERNAME, PASSWORD, SERVER_NAME

# NOTE! Substitute your own values for the following variables
server_name = SERVER_NAME # Name or IP address of your installation of Tableau Server
user_name = USERNAME    # User name to sign in as (e.g. admin)
password = PASSWORD
site_url_id = ""          # Site to sign in to. An empty string is used to specify the default site.

signin_url = "http://{}/api/3.1/auth/signin".format(server_name)

csv_url = "https://{}/#/views/Test/Dash/A.csv".format(server_name)

payload = { "credentials": { "name": user_name, "password": password, "site": {"contentUrl": site_url_id }}}

headers = {
  'accept': 'text/csv,application/json',
  'content-type': 'application/json'
}

# Send the request to the server
req = requests.post(signin_url, json=payload, headers=headers)
req.raise_for_status()

# Get the response
response = json.loads(req.content)

# Parse the response JSON. The response body will look similar
# to the following example:
#
# {
#    "credentials": {
#        "site": {
#            "id": "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
#            "contentUrl": ""
#        },
#        "user": {
#            "id": "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
#        },
#         "token": "AUTH-TOKEN"
#    }
# }


# Get the authentication token from the <credentials> element
token = response["credentials"]["token"]

# Get the site ID from the <site> element
site_id = response["credentials"]["site"]["id"]

print('Sign in successful!')
print('\tToken: {token}'.format(token=token))
print('\tSite ID: {site_id}'.format(site_id=site_id))

# Set the authentication header using the token returned by the Sign In method.
headers['X-tableau-auth']=token


csv_req = requests.get(csv_url, headers=headers)
# ... Make other calls here ...

csv_req.raise_for_status() 
print(csv_req.status_code) #200

with open('something.csv', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(csv_req.content)
```

This passes the authentication issue but I'm getting page source in the response as opposed to CSV file

page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:ng="" xmlns:tb=""><head ng-csp><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, maximum-scale=2"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="vizportal-config" data-buildId="6m6iytne3n8" data-staticAssetsUrlPrefix=""><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vizportal.css?6m6iytne3n8"><script src="/javascripts/api/tableau-2.2.2.min.js?6m6iytne3n8"></script><script src="vizportalMinLibs.js?6m6iytne3n8"></script><script src="vizportal.min.js?6m6iytne3n8"></script></head><body class="tb-body"><div ng-app="VizPortalRun" id="ng-app" tb-window-resize class="tb-app"><div ui-view="" class="tb-app-inner"></div><tb:react-toaster></tb:react-toaster><script type="text/ng-template" id="inline_stackedElement.html"><div tb-window-resize tb-left="left" tb-top="top" tb-right="right" tb-bottom="bottom" tb-visible="visible" class="tb-absolute"></div></script><tb:stacked-elements></tb:stacked-elements></div></body></html>
```

It'll be extremely helpful if anyone can please guide me how to get the text/csv response as opposed to html.

Comment: In the end, I used the tabcmd command-line utility and a python package that talks to it and handles all the authentication and files.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Yes! I also ended up doing the same

Comment: @Delighted I want to download full data set for a view and not only the summary data. Populate_csv only works for summary data. Do you have any recomandation?

Comment: @PyRar Sorry, I only worked with it for this one project and didnt get into anything like that